# VSTO Deployment not working on Computer without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, vsto

I have written a Outlook 2007 Add-In. I added a Setup Project to it, and it built the dependencies itself.

When installed on a computer without visual studio, I get the following error message in the "Trust Center COM Add-in Manager":

"Load Behavior: Not Loaded. The Managed Add-In Loader Failed to Initialize"

**Detected Dependencies**

[image]

**Application Folder**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VSTO Redistributable wasn't selected in the prerequisite.

Comment: In other words, we need to check the option, "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86 and x64)", right?

Comment: Yes, or package it seperately and include a check for that in your VSTO deployment script/package.